# java ArrayList & JDBC

Tags: java, collections, jdbc

```
public class UserBean<br>
{ 
 public String name; 
 public String role; 
} 

class Dao{ 
 ArrayList<UserBean> a = new ArrayList<UserBean>();
 String sql = "Select * from user";
 ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(sql);
 while(rs.next()){
 //----------Problem------------
 // i want to do something like<br>
  a.add[0].name = rs.getString("name");
  a.add[0].role = rs.getString("role");
 // Get column from resultset and set the value of userbean column
 }
}
```

Comment: sorry line no 9 is ArrayList<UserBean> a= new ArrayList<UserBean>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
public class UserBean {
    public String name;
    public String role;
}

class Dao{
    ArrayList<UserBean> a= new ArrayList<UserBean>();
    String sql = "Select * from user";
    ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()){
        UserBean ub = new UserBean();
        ub.name=rs.getString("name");
        ub.role=rs.getString("role");
        a.add(ub);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an instance of `UserBean` and add it to the `List`.

```
 while(rs.next()){
  UserBean bean=new UserBean();
  bean.name = rs.getString("name");
  bean.role = rs.getString("role");
  a.add(bean);
 // Get column from resultset and set the value of userbean column
 }
```